# Count number of inner groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to count the number of child groups.

For example.

My group is as follows:

```
Parent Group
      Child Group (on multiple columns)
```

Example:

```
Parent 1
    Child Group 1
        1
        2
        3
    Child Group 2
        1
        2
*Total: 2 *

Parent 2
    Child Group 1
        1
        2
*Total: 1 *
```

*This is the figure I'm trying to calculate. Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. I'm not sure how to format so the numbers appear on a new line.

Comment: To explain in words, For parent 1, it has 2 child groups (First child has 3 detail rows and second child has 2 detail rows). I want to be able to calculate the number of children in the parent group, which in this case is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Parent Group Scope you can just use something like:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ChildGroup.Value)
```

Substituting the name of your Child Group field as required.

For example, say your data is like this:

[image]

And you've set up a table with groups based on `Parent` and `ChildGroup`:

[image]

You can see I've added the above expression to the Parent Group footer row - it will count all the Child groups in the Scope of the current parent.

The report works as required:

[image]